# Add all table names of my database to combo Box

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

```
public void show()
{
       ds = new DataSet();
       ada = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from    sys.tables", conn);
       //ada = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from emp",    conn);
       //ds = new DataSet();
       ada.Fill(ds);
}  

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs    e)
{
       conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ASHISH-PC\SQLEXPRESS; initial    catalog=ashish; integrated security=true");
       show();
       foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
       {
           comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.TableName[0]);
       }
}
```

Comment: I've formatted your code for you. It still does not look like a complete question....

Comment: And your question is? (Hint: questions that consist *solely* of code are rarely clear.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add all table name of my database in combo box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540985/how-to-add-all-table-name-of-my-database-in-combo-box)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're just looking for something quick and dirty. Currently you are returning the name of the DataTable object. You need something like:

```
            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                }
            }
```

Like I said, quick and dirty.